# How do I assign a CSS class based on if it's the current page?

Tags: php, html, css

I've created a modular web page in which each component is within it's own html/php file. Example, index.html calls up header.html, content.php, etc. The reason, so I can keep each section clean, and separate.

My header.php includes a navigational bar (which also uses CSS3 to provide drop down menu (ex, DEF):

```
<div id="nav">
<ul><li class="navlist"<a href="abc.html">ABC</a></li>
<li class="navlist"><a href="def.html">DEF</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#ghi.html"><li>GHI</li></a>
  <li><a href="#jkl.html">JKL</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="navlist"><a href="mno.html">MNO</a></li>
</ul>
```

My dilemma is that I want the 'li class' to equal 'nav_active_menu' if it is the current page being viewed.

I'm assuming that PHP can take care of this, but unsure as to how. Can anyone provide any examples, or links on how to do this?

Hopefully this makes sense.. words....

Comment: Without any PHP code it is impossible to tell. You must have some logic to determine the current page and with that it should be quite simple like `<li class="..<?php if (isActive('abc')) print " active"; ?>">`

Comment: Well, this is a topic which is prominently featured in PHP tutorials. Honestly, how long did you research it before asking? Also, as I said, without the PHP it is impossible to give a correct answer, which is why I personally downvoted

Comment: I was looking at a few things via Google search, but I think you and Abu made it much more clear. Many thanks.

Comment: "few things" isn't much. For the questions I have posted, I researched and tried for hours (if not days), and still received a few downvotes on one of them ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by making $activePage variable before you include the header.php page

in you abc.php file:

```
$activePage = "abc";
include('header.php');
```

and in your header.php file:

```
<li class="<?php if ($activePage == "abc") echo 'nav_active_menu'; ?>"><a href="abc.html">ABC</a></li>
```

The same way for other pages but with a different value with $activePage variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, using javascript with jquery.

Add a specific CSS class to each parent li:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="navlist abc"><a href="abc.html">ABC</a></li>
    <li class="navlist def"><a href="def.html">DEF</a>
       <ul>
            <li><a href="#ghi.html">GHI</li></a>
            <li><a href="#jkl.html">JKL</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navlist mno"><a href="mno.html">MNO</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then add jquery javascript to your `<head>` in the HTML.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add this to your CSS:

```
.nav_active_menu {your css for active_item goes here}
```

And in each HTML page add the relevant jquery selector to activate:

```
<script>
$(".def a").first().addClass('nav_active_menu');
</script>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmfncbb7/2/ (fiddle updated with the correct class)

Comment: Sorry, but this seems like an overkill. What if the user does not have JS enabled? Also you'll need to add the JS code to every page and the class to every link (not very maintainable). Why not use a general solution as suggested by my comment or AbuOmar's answer?